# EF Core strange behaviour

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 3.0 code first. I have this loop:

```
foreach (var profileCount in quantity)
{
    //here I get the exception:
    var oldItem = dc.Stock.Items.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Profile.Id == profileCount.Key); 

    if (oldItem == null)
    {
        dc.Stock.Items.Add(new Item
        {
            Price = 0,
            ProfileId = profileCount.Key,
            Quantity = profileCount.Value,
            WasChanged = false
        });
    }
}
```

`Stock.Items` is empty(not null). First iteration works fine, on the second one I get

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I guess it's because I add and try to read from the same collection, but I'm not sure why exactly this is happening.

Comment: try `dbcontext.savechanges()` after every add.

Comment: have a looks at `a.Profile.Id` condition. you are setting `profileCount.Key` to `ProfileId `

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla yes, Profile.Id was the case, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @IanKemp, no, this is a bit different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert your first item (`dc.Stock.Items.Add(new Item`) you don't add a `Profile`, so on the next iteration `a.Profile.Id` will be a `NullReferenceException`.

Either assign a `Profile` when you add a new item, or check for null in your `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Thanks, it was the case